# Xamarin form chat Implementation

Tags: xamarin.forms, twilio, chat

Please someone help me implement chat application in Xamarin form.

I have tried https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/app-monkeychat link to implement. But I did not found package Ip Messaging Package in neuget.

Highly appreciate your help.
Thank you

Comment: Follow the steps explained on Twilio's official webite : https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/05/how-to-build-android-chat-apps-using-xamarin-and-twilio.html

Comment: @HimanshuDwivedi The package "Twilio ip messaging" not present in xamarin form nuget. Is their any alternative for this?.. thanks

Comment: it's there in Nuget https://www.nuget.org/profiles/twilio-api, if you are not getting this in Nuget search result, install directly from Package manager console

Comment: @HimanshuDwivedi Thank you very much.. I will try this one.

Comment: @HimanshuDwivedi for your kind information "Twilio ip messaging" is not support to install in latest xamarin form standard build :(

Answer (score 0):

Monkey chat is using the Twilio library, have you thought about using SignalR?

https://montemagno.com/real-time-communication-for-mobile-with-signalr/

And others -

- https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-a-chat-app-using-asp-net-and-xamarin-android-with-signalr/
- https://developer.telerik.com/products/real-time-mobile-apps-with-appbuilder-xamarin-and-signalr/ (depends on telerik though)
- https://medium.com/@edgarleonardo/websockets-implementation-with-signalr-and-xamarin-forms-d9244fa128da

There should be enough information across all those articles to allow you to get started on your application.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I want to integrate Twilio API to my project. Do  you have any step by step documentation or source code  to look into? Thank you

Comment: Sorry @AshwiniPatkar - by the "quick" looks (I may be wrong) of https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/tutorials/chat-application-csharp-mvc it all looks quite of out date and not very Xamarin friendly.  You could wrap the ios/android SDKs with your own custom bindings, but ...